# Date from String in Swift but it becomes the previous day

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to create a day from a string (mSince) :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from:mSince as! String)!
```

and the print values are:

mSince = Optional(2021-04-25)

newDate = 2021-04-24 21:00:00 +0000

I could not figure out why newDate becomes the previous day.

Thank you!

Comment: The date is correct. Your time zone is UTC +0300. And the print out is UTC. `2021-04-25 00:00:00 +0300` and `2021-04-24 21:00:00 +0000` is the same point in time

Comment: Thank you. What would be a good way to match the time zones? Because I am trying to subtract two dates and in gives me irrational outputs when the timezones are different..

Comment: Set the time zone property on the date formatter to the needed time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example of how to create dates from multiple UTC timezones and an example of how to get the delta (in seconds) between the dates:

```
extension Date {
            static func - (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> TimeInterval {
                return lhs.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - rhs.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            }
        }

let utcDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
utcDateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
utcDateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

// Set the timeZone to the device’s local time zone. 
utcDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

let date1 = Date()
print(utcDateFormatter.string(from: date1))

// Parsing a string date
let dateString1 = "May 11, 2020 at 4:23:11 AM"
let utcDate1 = utcDateFormatter.date(from: dateString1)

// Set a date for a different timeZone (2 hours difference)
utcDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)
// Printing a Date
let date2 = Date()
print(utcDateFormatter.string(from: date2))

// Parsing a string representing a date
let dateString2 = "May 11, 2020 at 4:23:11 AM"
let utcDate2 = utcDateFormatter.date(from: dateString2)

let diff = utcDate1! - utcDate2!
print(diff)
```